# How to delete the particular Linux from Linux dual boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu and was trying to install Porteus to pendrive. But I accidentally installed it to hard disk where I was using bodhi linux.

Now I use Lubuntu from second partition and it is good to use. I want to remove bodhi linux from first partition without loosing data.

I tried to copy data from that partition but in last it says `can't copy data permission denied read only file system`

I think I need to boot in bodhi linux for that data but I am unable to boot in.

Someone please help me to remove bodhi linux from the first partition without loosing data.

Comment: Post this in question above: `sudo parted -l` Are you sure you did not overwrite the first partition?

Comment: Sorry but i have my data copied and deleted that partition, i used that hdd in windows 10 as usb media and copied all important data, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not manually mount read only? Auto mounts are read write and then can fail if not writable.  Use your drive sda, sdb etc for sdX and partition for Y.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/bodhi
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdXY /mnt/bodhi
```

Comment: thanks for answer, as u guided, i tried that but still not working

Answer (score 0):

That issue is solved as i used that Hard Disk as removable media in windows 10 and copied all important data.